# Save images in Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

Outlook 2007 no longer allows you to save images that are embedded in emails / feeds.
Specifically, I'm not referring to attachments (there is an easy workaround there), but to images "embedded" in html messages, i.e. the email has a reference to an online image.

Is there any workaround for this, or is anyone here familiar with a script, macro, or "hack" of any other kind?

Comment: Thanks for the responses, but I was looking for a way click a menu/button and save the embedded file. @tnorthcutt's macro suggestion would be great, but it doesnt work for html embedded images.

Answer (score 2):

This is a workaround:

If you right click and choose 'copy' then try to paste to your (active) desktop, you will be prompted to save the image.  You will then be given an opportunity to save it.

Another workaround is to save the message as HTML, which will produce a folder for resources, one of which is your image.

Answer (score 0):

[Instructions for creating a macro](http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/saveembeddedpictures.htm) to do this for you.  Alternatively, can you right-click, copy, and paste in an image editor?  [This page](http://www.techproszone.net/blog/index.php/2009/08/26/how-to-save-an-embedded-picture-in-outlook-2007/) also has instructions for opening the image in a web browser to save.

Comment: Thanks, I've seen both those links, but the macro only saves attached images, not embedded (i.e. linked from HTML mail). have anything similar for those?

Answer (score 0):

At first You need to copy the embedded image and Then.....

paste into an image editor like Paint or Photoshop. All Windows users have Paint on their machine (under Programs | Accessories). Open up the image editor to a blank image then paste. 
And then You can save in Your Drive.

I hope it will be helpful for you.